# Automapper 4.2, How to re use the mappings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a automapper mapping that work's just fine , I just don't know if I'll have to re-write it everytime I need to map my model to my viewModel vice-versa. I wonder if there is a way where once it is mapped, automapper knows what to do.
I could create static methods with the mappings in one "helper" class, but I don't know if it is the right approach.
Here is the mapping.

```
                    var ax =
                new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.cod_endereco, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.codigo))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.logradouro, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.logradouro))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.cod_tipolograd, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.tipo.codigo))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.cod_munic_ender, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.municipio.codigo))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.nome_munic_ender, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.municipio.nome))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.numero, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.numero))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.complemento, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.complemento))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.cep, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.cep))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.bairro, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.endereco.bairro))
                    ;
                }).CreateMapper().Map<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>(p);
```

If I use the mapping like below:

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>()).CreateMapper().Map<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>(p);
```

the fields that I used forMember method to map them, stays null.

Comment: I dont understand. You need to configure the mapping just one time, typycally in application start. Once a mapping between 2 types is configured you can simply use Automapper.Mapper.Map<TSource,TDest> and do the transformation.

Comment: Solved it creating a MapperConfiguration and IMapper objects in the MvcApplication classe at the Global.asax , and on Application_Start method I add my Automapper profiles to the configuration therefore I can use the same mapper and the same MapperConfiguration in the whole application